# Woocommerce - Add To Cart and Buy Now buttons on Product Pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am attempting to add a buy now button in Woocommerce on the product page so there are two buttons:

1. add to cart
2. buy now (which will add the product to the cart and redirect to checkout)

I still want add to cart to function as usual.

How can I achieve this? Many thanks.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/woocommerce/

Answer (score 5):

I managed to resolve this by finding this blog post http://samplacette.com/skip-shopping-cart-in-woocommerce/.

If anyone else finds that they are struggling to implement this, this is how I did it (might not be the best solution but it works for me):

I copied the following text into my theme functions.php

```
/** * Set cart item quantity action *
* Only works for simple products (with integer IDs, no colors etc) *
* @access public
* @return void */
function woocommerce_set_cart_qty_action() { 
    global $woocommerce;
    foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $quantity) {
    // only allow integer quantities
    if (! is_numeric($quantity)) continue;

        // attempt to extract product ID from query string key
        $update_directive_bits = preg_split('/^set-cart-qty_/', $key);
        if (count($update_directive_bits) >= 2 and is_numeric($update_directive_bits[1])) {
            $product_id = (int) $update_directive_bits[1]; 
            $cart_id = $woocommerce->cart->generate_cart_id($product_id);
            // See if this product and its options is already in the cart
            $cart_item_key = $woocommerce->cart->find_product_in_cart( $cart_id ); 
            // If cart_item_key is set, the item is already in the cart
            if ( $cart_item_key ) {
                $woocommerce->cart->set_quantity($cart_item_key, $quantity);
            } else {
                // Add the product to the cart 
                $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity);
            }
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'init', 'woocommerce_set_cart_qty_action' );
```

And then I modified *theme*/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php (make sure you don't midify the plugin files so make a copy and paste into your theme files into a woocommerce folder) to the following (notice that I had removed my quantity input from my code so if you need it,ensure you rework the code to get it working):

```
<form class="cart single-product" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->id ); ?>" />
    <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt cart-buttton add-to-cart"><?php echo $product->single_add_to_cart_text(); ?></button>
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>
</form>

<form class="cart single-product" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' action="/checkout?set-cart-qty_<?php echo $product->id;?>=1">
    <button type="submit"  class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt cart-buttton buy-now">Buy Now</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->id ); ?>" />
</form>
```

I added another button next to the existing Add to Cart button but separating the form. The blog post mentions that you can add a hyperlink instead but the above worked for me in terms of the way I needed to customise the page (slightly more long winded)

**From blog:**

> Usage instructions:
>
> Create a hyperlink with a query string argument like so:
>   ?set-cart-qty_=
>   Where  is the numerical ID of your product (something like “167”) and  is the >quantity you want set in the user’s shopping cart (most likely this will just be “1”).
>
> Example URL to send user to checkout with exactly one item of product with ID “167” in cart:
>
> http://my.website.com/checkout?set-cart-qty_167=1

I hope the above helps anyone who has a similar problem as I had.

Answer (score 0):

After much searching I was surprised this is not something that is standard.
Here was my solution:

Either use a hook like "woocommerce_single_product_summary"

Or copy the wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php to your child theme like:
wp-content/themes/child-theme/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php

Edit the file and add the following code where you want the button to appear:

```
<div class="express-checkout-wrapper">
            <a id="dc_express_checkout" href="/checkout/?add-to-cart=<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">
                Purchase
            </a>
        </div>
```

Now the only problem is the button will take you to checkout and add the correct product but without the correct quantity if you changed it so I used js in my custom.js file that is queued in the footer:

```
// Add and change quantity to express checkout button when the quantity is updated
if($('.cart .qty').length){
    var originalUrl = $('#dc_express_checkout').attr('href');
    $('.cart .qty').change(function(){
        var url = originalUrl + '&quantity=' + $(this).val();
        $('#dc_express_checkout').attr('href', url);
    });
}
```

You can change the url from:

```
href="/checkout/?add-to-cart=<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>"
```

to:

```
href="/cart/?add-to-cart=<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>"
```

If you want the button to direct to the cart instead of the checkout page.