# Creating a "buy now" web addresses for WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, api, woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce online store. I am wondering if instead of asking users to enter the shop and click "add to cart" every time, we could make for each product a special address in the style of AliExpress's "buy now" button - a button that leads directly to a basket including one unit of that product so that the user will only have to put his credit card.

How can I create such an address?

Comment: See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26984384/woocommerce-add-to-cart-and-buy-now-buttons-on-product-pages).

Comment: @burf Thanks but the question is about web address and not about adding the buttons to the website. Our planning is to do QR codes in the physical store and put them next to products so people can pay easily.

Comment: Did you try the `/checkout/?add-to-cart=`?

Answer (score 0):

To create a direct "Add to Cart" link for a specific product in WooCommerce, you can use the product's unique URL with a query parameter specifying the quantity to add to the cart. Here's an example of how you can construct the link:

```
https://yourdomain.com/?add-to-cart=123&quantity=1
```

add-to-cart=PRODUCT_ID

Comment: this adds the product to the cart. I want to move to the checkout step immediately after.

Comment: Hi, Heidar Ammarloo!

You posted 9 answers in June that appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT), with *five* of these having comments that said that the answer didn't work. Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and continue to be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.